# Detecting simultaneous key presses in python

Tags: python-2.7

I want to present several stimuli. After each stimulus, two simultaneous keypresses are requested.
Only one key is responsible to present the next stimulus. Both shall be logged. How do i get both of them in python?

I tried it like this:

```
kb = keyboard(keylist = ['f','g','h','j','<','-','d','k'])
Break = canvas()
Break.text('')
A = canvas()
A.text('A')
B = canvas()
B.text('B')
seq = [A,B]*5 
seq.reverse() #pop wählt von hinten aus
var.T_Resp=[]
var.T_Resp2=[]
var.Resp=[]
var.Resp2=[]
var.Stim=[]
var.T_Stim=[]
last=None
last2=None
t =seq[-1].show()
var.T_Stim.append(t)
if seq[-1] == A:
    var.Stim.append('A')
else:
    var.Stim.append('B')
print var.Stim, t
seq.pop() #pops out the last
while True:
    if (len(seq)!=0):
        key, time = kb.get_key(timeout=0)
        if key == 'f':
            var.T_Resp2.append(time)
            var.Resp2.append(key)
            print key, time
            kb.flush()    
        elif key == '-':
            print key, time
            var.T_Resp.append(time)
            var.Resp.append(key)
            t = seq[-1].show()
            var.T_Stim.append(t)
            if seq[-1] == A:
                var.Stim.append('A')
            else:
                var.Stim.append('B')
            print var.Stim, t
            seq.pop()
    if (len(seq)==0): #Last presses
        key, time = kb.get_key(timeout=0)
        if key == 'f':
            var.T_Resp2.append(time)
            var.Resp2.append(key)
            print key, time
            if (time-t)>200:
                last2=time
            kb.flush() 
        elif key == '-':
            print key, time
            var.T_Resp.append(time)
            var.Resp.append(key)
            last=time
        elif last>0 and last2>0:
            print "Break", var.T_Resp, var.T_Resp2
            break
        elif last2==None and len(var.Resp)>9 :
            print "Break", var.T_Resp, var.T_Resp2
            break

    #log.write_vars() #NOT POSSIBLE: slows down the whole loop

for i in range(len(var.Stim)):
    var.Stim1=var.Stim[i]
    var.T_Stim1=var.T_Stim[i]
    log.write_vars()
    print var.Stim1, var.T_Stim1

for i in range(len(var.Resp)):
    var.Resp1=var.Resp[i]
    var.T_Resp1=var.T_Resp[i]
    log.write_vars()
    print var.Resp1, var.T_Resp1

for i in range(len(var.Resp2)):
    var.Resp2_1=var.Resp2[i]
    var.T_Resp2_1=var.T_Resp2[i]
    log.write_vars()
    print var.Resp2_1, var.T_Resp2_1

print "Resp", len(var.Resp), "Resp2", len(var.Resp2)

for i in range(len(var.T_Resp)):
    print "IOI", var.T_Resp[i]-var.T_Resp2[i]
```

However, this does not work nicely for two reasons:

1) Sometimes a key press is not recognized. I wonder whether this is when the keys are pressed exactly simultaneous.

2) In my output the inter onset intervals (IOI) [interval between two simultaneous presses] are not normally distributed. There are only certain numbers e.g. -29, -2, 2, 29 (and because of variable delay in very few cases +-1). Where does this come from?

I am using open sesame.

Comment: Yes, keypresses from a person. Of course they are usually not simultaneous. But sometimes they are (on at least miliseconds).

Comment: Note that keyboards usually can't detect all keys individually, so when certain keys is pressed down, the keyboard will not register certain other keys any more, because they are wired in a kind of "grid (does not match physical key cap layout grid), where the keyboard only detects grid row and column and gets key from intersection, which works fine as long as you don't press many keys on same row/column.